# iOS Mail automatically switching account, depending on recipient

Tags: ios, mail.app, email

My Mail app switches from my iCloud account to Gmail when sending an Email to a Gmail contact. How can I disable this?

Comment: Are you sure that your iCloud email is selected as the default account in your Settings?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are probably replying to the message from inside your gmail inbox which will use the gmail account as the sending authority since the email was sent to this account in the first place. The error therefor isn't with the mail.app it is with the way that your emails are sent to you.

If you want to change the address in which you send your email from just tap on your gmail address and switch it to your iCloud address.

If you don't want to have the automatic reply address to be your gmail one I suggest not using the address to receive emails to.

All that mail.app can do for default address is to ensure that your iCloud account is the address that is used when you compose a new email.

Comment: Nope. I am writing a new Mail. Even so by sharing in Safari. It starts out with iCloud and switches to gmail when I enter the Gmail recepient.

Comment: Is there any way that you can show a video of this happening because I am unable to replicate your problem. I have tried every instance and iCloud is still my default address.

Comment: It's crazy, but I wanted to take a video just now, and the behavior has disappeared. All that happened in between was a reboot of the device. Probably just a glitch? I will try to reproduce it and come back if I can.

Comment: ok will still try to help if you do.

Comment: I can only conclude that it is the bug. I am using iOS 10.3.3 and this issue still exists in my iPhone and iPad. More discussions can be found in the address below but still no solution yet. Please post if you find any solution. Thanks. https://discussions.apple.com/thread/6503313?start=0&tstart=0